# Laravel mail setupSwift_TransportException: Expected response code 250 but got code "", with message ""

Tags: php, email, laravel-5, swiftmailer

There are similar questions asked here before. But that are not helping me around solving the problem. This is my current mail configuration in .env file of my laravel file:

```
   MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
   MAIL_HOST=****.prod.sin2.secureserver.net
   MAIL_PORT=465
   MAIL_USERNAME=****@somedomain.com
   MAIL_PASSWORD=*****
   MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

I've re verified the mail server and credentials. They are accurate and it establishes a connection while tried with `php artisan tinker`from command prompt with similar response while using the Mail facade of Laravel.

Please help me with this.

Comment: I once had this problem because of an incorrect nginx config, what does your `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` show?

Comment: @jagsler I have this exact problem, this is the output of my server name: ~^(?.*)$  Is that the problem?

Comment: @raysn0w I think so, the server name should output a normal string without any regex in it. Don't know if you're also using nginx but I fixed it with adding `fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $host;` to the php block in my nginx config

Comment: I've found the answer. Thanks for your contribution (:

Comment: fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $host; was the fix, thanks a lot @raysn0w

Answer (score 2):

Just in case some had the same problem as me, with SMTP and Gmail configuration, my problem was an **incorrect** server name configured on nginx.  You can test this by echoing $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] if you have something like I did: **~^(?.*)$** its going to throw that error.

You need to check you nginx config and test the output of the server name.

Thanks to  @jagsler for pointing this in the comments.